# Why my function is not a function?

Tags: javascript, html

I have this in my view page:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="toggle_SITEID" name="@@toggle_SITEID" onclick="toggle_SITEID(this)" /> New <br />
```

then in my js file I have this:

```
toggle_SITEID = function (chk) {
    // something
}
```

and then I click checkbox, "something" won't run. I check in firebug console the error message was:

> toggle_SITEID is not a function

So why is it?

Comment: Are you including your javascript file in your HTML?

Comment: Is it in the right scope? i.e. is `toggle_SITEID` a variable in some other function, not in the global namespace?

Comment: I suspect this is a scope issue, can you give access to the whole file?

Comment: @djlumley yes I include the file.

Comment: @minitech no, it's only this function name.

Comment: @tobyodavies I'm sorry, what do you mean?

Comment: Can you post a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) that reproduces the problem, please? (Make sure to set the JavaScript location to "no wrap (head)", too)

Comment: I suspect you have `var toggle_SITEID` somewhere, or the JS file is included from within a frame.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/PsXP4/ - works perfectly, you're doing something wrong elsewhere.

Comment: @tobyodavies the problem is occured after I added "_SITEID" and I check there is no other variable named by that. I bring back the old function toggle and it works fine

Comment: If the element has a property with the same name as the function, it will break. This also applies to the `document` element. Your HTML doesn't show any attribute with the exact name `toggle_SITEID`. Any chance you've added a property to the element with that name, or to the `document`?

Comment: @amnotiam actually input ID is 'toggle_SITEID' too, I thought it doesn't matter so I dont write it. if u dont mind you can write the answer, you're right

Comment: I'm sorry guys, I'll edit the question, thx for the help :)

Comment: @amnotiam. I made a community wiki with all the options.

Comment: Mr.Rendezvous: The issue I had in mind was a situation where you have an attribute like `toggle_SITEID = "foo"` on the element, or you did `document.toggle_SITEID = "foo"`. In both cases, the inline handler becomes a variable in the scope chain of the event handler. Seems that what @gdoron described below is the issue you were having.

Comment: @amnotiam. Please elaborate more in the CW answer(but don't tell the community or they will be upset...) what did you mean, because it does work in chrome(but no in IE) [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Fyw39/2/).

Comment: @gdoron: I'll do that. My last comment was off. I'll give the description in your CW.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There could be couple of reasons for this error:

- You didn't reference the script in the HTML file.
- The function isn't declared in the global scope but in an inner scope.
  global scope- [**WORKING DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Fyw39/)
  inner scope - [**NON WORKING DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Fyw39/1/)
- There is an element whose `id` is the same as the function name(`toggle_SITEID`).
  In Internet Explorer, using an element's `id` is a shortcut for `document.getElementById()`. Break the link by using a `var` declaration.
- Another issue that can arise is when you have an inline handler that tries to use a global variable that interferes with the unique scope chain of inline handlers. That happens when the global...

  - has the same name as any property on the element with the handler, or
  - has the same name as any property on the `document`

  Since the scope chain of an inline handler has the element itself, as well as the `document`, injected into the scope chain as variable objects, any property on those objects will interfere when accessing global variables.

  For example, given this element: `<a onclick="foo();">click me</a>`, we can successfully invoke the global `foo()` *unless* we've done something like `document.foo = "bar"`. Since the `document` is injected as a variable object in the scope chain, the `document.foo` now shadows the global `foo`.

  Same goes with the element itself. If we add the `foo` property to the element before invoking the global function, that property will shadow the global. `<a onclick="this.foo = 'bar'; foo();">click me</a>`

Comment: The problem is that he didn't close his variable declaration, so the function is never actually set to the variable.  I can't tell from his example how you can tell the scope of the function.

Comment: Maybe it works without, but I say the js is wrong. as in it doesn't make sense to set a var to an anon function and not finish setting the var.  BUt you are right, it does work either way. But you haven't indicated (to me at least) how you can tell how he set his scope. Are you guessing based on the error?

Comment: @Anthony. It's not wrong but not best practice. anyway, yes it was a guess, his real error was spotted by **@am not I am**. So I added all the guesses and made a community wiki out of it.

Comment: Why did you make this answer CW?

Comment: @ThiefMaster. Because not all of the answers(including the [right answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10202645/why-my-function-is-not-a-function/10203532#comment13102161_10202645) )are mine, so didn't want to get the credit. and am not i am would have make it CW him self..) You can improve it now if you wish.

Comment: @gdoron: I actually had a slightly different issue *(which affects all browsers)* in mind in my comment above, but I completely forgot about the IE issue with id attribute becoming a global reference to the element. So I think you nailed it.

Comment: I tested it with NAME value is the same as function_name, it has the same error. so it's not only for ID

Answer (score 2):

The error for me was the the ID was the same name as the function.

Change the id to something else different to the function name you aim to call on-click.

Change

```
<input type="checkbox" id="toggle_SITEID" name="@@toggle_SITEID" onclick="toggle_SITEID(this)" /> New <br />
```

To:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="toggle_SITEID" name="@@toggle_SITEID" onclick="toggle_SITE_ID(this)" /> New <br />
```

Answer (score -2):

One thing jumps out at me:

You don't end it with a semi-colon, even though it's an anonymous function.

Try this:

```
toggle_SITEID = function (chk) {
    alert("I work!");
};
```

Working Demo at: http://jsfiddle.net/crazytonyi/cDNcu/

Comment: That one that jump out at you is wrong... You didn't test it. Your's fiddle without the semi-colon works... [Check it out](http://jsfiddle.net/cDNcu/1/)

Comment: If you read the ecmascript specification: http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-262.htm you can see that semicolons are infact, completely optional (although people like Douglas Crockford get angry when you don't use them).

Comment: yup, almost all my function didn't end with semicolon and it's still working